# UIView is removed when scrolling in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiview

I've created a tableView with a custom cell. In the nib file i've created a `UIView` named `borderView`. The issue is that when i scroll up or down and then scroll back it removes this borderView? What could be the reason for this?

I've  added a UIView to the xib file and then connected it to this property in the `UITableViewCell`

```
@IBOutlet weak var borderView: UIView!
```

then in `awakeFromNib()`

```
borderView.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: "#e6e6e6")
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen when the cells disappear from the screen when your scroll and then when they appear again? If so you would like to take a look at your

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

Since there might be something on that method that overrides your UIVIew.